# flask route requesting Authorization header when not annotated with jwt_required

Tags: python, jwt, flask-jwt

I'm using the flask-jwt-extended library to provide authorization for an API with the following route:

```
@app.route('/<string:stage>/api/v2.0/unauth/token', methods=['POST'])
def get_token(stage):
    username = request.json['username']
    password = request.json['password']
    user = get_user(username)
    if user and user.password == password:
        return jsonify({'access_token': create_access_token(identity=username)}), 200
    else:
        abort(401)
```

When I make the following CURL request

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"username":"android", "password":"59a07c1a-0ec9-41a0-9b96-2ff196f35f0c"}' http://0.0.0.0:5000/staging/api/v2.0/unauth/token
```

the server responds with

```
{
  "msg": "Missing Authorization Header"
}
```

despite the fact that there is no `jwt_required` annotation on the `get_token` function. I know that the username and password passed to the request are valid, the object returned from the `get_user` call is valid, and other non-jwt_required-annotated and jwt_required-annotated routes work as expected. I've tried renaming the endpoint, and even moving it in the code to a different spot but to no avail. How can this be fixed?

Comment: Are you sure there is no other route matching your request?

Comment: I am. A search for `token` pulls up this function only, and changing the name of the route doesn't fix the issue either.

Comment: That alone does not prove much, since it could be interpreted as an argument.  I suggest running `app.url_map.match("/staging/api/v2.0/unauth/token", method="POST")` in `flask shell` and seeing what it comes up with.

Comment: As a side note, you definitely shouldn't be storing plain text passwords.

Comment: Are you using any other flask extensions that may be adding or handling routes? (flask-restless, that sort of thing)

Comment: This code is just from the test api; the real api has salts passwords; thank you though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there has to be something else going on in your application. If we take a minimum application based on what you have there, it works correctly:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request, abort
from flask_jwt_extended import JWTManager, create_access_token

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'super-secret'  # Change this!

# Setup the Flask-JWT-Extended extension
jwt = JWTManager(app)

@app.route('/<string:stage>/api/v2.0/unauth/token', methods=['POST'])
def get_token(stage):
    username = request.json['username']
    password = request.json['password']
    if username == 'test' and password == 'test':
        return jsonify({'access_token': create_access_token(identity=username)}), 200
    else:
        abort(401)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

and

```
$ curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"username":"test", "password":"test"}' http://0.0.0.0:5000/staging/api/v2.0/unauth/token

{
  "access_token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJleHAiOjE0OTQ5NTI3MjMsImlhdCI6MTQ5NDk1MTgyMywibmJmIjoxNDk0OTUxODIzLCJqdGkiOiJhMTM0ZjU0MS03NDliLTRjODctYTA1ZC02NDU0MDBlMTQ2YTIiLCJpZGVudGl0eSI6InRlc3QiLCJmcmVzaCI6ZmFsc2UsInR5cGUiOiJhY2Nlc3MiLCJ1c2VyX2NsYWltcyI6e319.rXyi7p97tiplzyPq_7AtDsu0gUlrOhQmcak9bn2LOaU"
}
```

If you can post more of your code, maybe we could help track down what is going on?

Also, to mirror what Sven said, you should never be storing/comparing passwords in plain text. If this was just as an example for posting to stackoverflow, then no problem. But if your real code is the same, you should look into salting and hashing your passwords.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. It turns out the call to `get_user` was causing the problem. I renamed the method to `get_user_by_username` and it works.